# Tomcat Deploy .war file doesn't run

Tags: java, xml, tomcat, war

I'm trying to deploy my .war file from Tomcat 8 with Ja, for running it in Postman. However, when I try to deploy and it is not shown in Postman. Below are the given exceptions that causes this issue. What can i do to solve this problem?

```
org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [C:\Users\berkt\eclipse-workspace\Test\apache-tomcat-8.5.32\webapps\Restful.war]

    04-Jul-2018 14:08:31.081 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processServletContainerInitializers Unable to process ServletContainerInitializer for [org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.init.JerseyServletContainerInitializer]. This is most likely due to a class defined in the @HandlesTypes annotation being missing. Enable DEBUG level logging for the full stack trace.
    04-Jul-2018 14:08:31.541 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start:
     org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component 
    [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Restful]]
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:985)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Also, i'm using this xml file:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?> 
<web-app xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
   xmlns = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"  
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"  
   id = "WebApp_ID" version = "3.0"> 
   <display-name>User Management</display-name> 
   <servlet> 
      <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name> 
      <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class> 
      <init-param> 
         <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name> 
         <param-value>TestRestful</param-value> 
      </init-param> 
   </servlet> 
   <servlet-mapping> 
      <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name> 
      <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern> 
   </servlet-mapping>   
</web-app>
```

Comment: `jersey.config.server.provider.packages` is supposed to be a package name, and `TestRestful` looks like a class name, not a package name, since package name are all lowercase according to Java naming conventions.

Comment: You are missing a class or library. "This is most likely due to a class defined in the @HandlesTypes annotation being missing. "

Comment: *"What can i do to solve this problem?"* **Step 1:** Read the error message: *Unable to process ServletContainerInitializer for [org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.init.JerseyServletContainerInitializer]. This is most likely due to a class defined in the `@HandlesTypes` annotation being missing. Enable DEBUG level logging for the full stack trace.* --- **Step 2:** Examine the `@HandlesTypes` annotations in your code. --- **Step 3:** If that doesn't fix it, do what error message says, then try again to get full stack trace.